# Perl looping through an array of hashes, gives Can't use string ("password") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at

Tags: perl

Trying to loop through an array of hashes and getting an error message that I don't understand.

Below is the code that creates the array of hashes, using Dumper It appears to have all every thing in it. And like this it runs fine.

```
while ($getAdUserInfo->fetch()){

$name = $name || '';
$isactive = $isactive || ''; 
$loginid = $loginid || '';
$account_status = $account_status || '';
$password = $password || '';
#print "$name, $isactive, $loginid, $account_status, $password\n"; 
my %row = (
    name => $name, 
    isactive => $isactive, 
    loginid => $loginid, 
    account_status => $account_status, 
    password => $password,
);
push(@adUserInfo, %row);
}
```

But if I add this code to loop through it

```
for my $rowRef (@adUserInfo)  {
print $rowRef->{password};
}
```

I get this error Can't use string ("password") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at adempiereToExo.pl line 64

Now I have done a bit of reading on this error and most of the time it looks like it happens  when someone has something in the array that is not a hash ref. But I don't think that is the case here. I am extremely new to Perl so I could be wrong. Also it is always the last element in the hash that it moans about?

I Know there are a lot of people asking about this error, But I have read through a lot of answers and still cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
push(@adUserInfo, %row);
```

(which means "expand `%row`'s keys and values out into a list, and add all of them to `@aduserInfo`"; you can add a `print "@adUserInfo\n"` to get a clearer idea of that) to this:

```
push(@adUserInfo, \%row);
```

(which means "create a reference to `%row`, and add that reference to `@aduserInfo`").

> Also it is always the last element in the hash that it moans about?

That's arbitrary. Hashes are unordered, so there's no concept of a "last element".

Comment: Using "x @adUserInfo" in the Perl debugger would also be helpful to find what's going on (i.e. what went wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following two options should work:

1. `push @adUserInfo, \%row;`
2. `push @adUserInfo, {%row};`

They both push a hashref onto the array stack, the first does so by dereferencing the hash.  The second creates a hashref by breaking the hash into a list and putting the contents of that list into a hashref.

---

Your error is coming because `$rowRef` is looping through the array, which instead of being an array of hashrefs, is an one-dimensional array of the hash's keys and values.  I think the interpreter is seeing your code as `"password"->{password}`, and its error is right, you can't use a string as a hashref.